# Object in a vector in an object in a vector sometimes gets erased when I try to copy it and push the copy in the same vector

Tags: c++, object, vector, reference, copy

Sorry, the title is a bit messy, but i'll try to explain it: On top level, I have a vector of objects (lets call it vectorA). Now i want to copy one of those objects (objectA) in vectorA, and push the copy (objectA') in vectorA. No need for a deep copying copy constructor, because the object contains only simple vars and one vector (vectorB) of other objects (objectB). 
Everything gets copied correctly, and most of the time it works. But every now and then, after copying objectA correctly, when pushing objectA' in VectorA, in objectA the address of the first objectB in vectorB gets set to NULL.

As a diagram:

VectorA > ObjectA > VectorB > ObjectB (this gets set to NULL)

Simplified Code:

```
for (auto &objectA: vectorA) {
   ClassA objectA' = objectA;
   // Everything is copied correctly, the references to every attribute are different
   vectorA.push_back(objectA');
   // Now it's messed up, the reference to the first objectB in vectorB in objectA is NULL
}
```

Comment: It seems broken to try and grow the container you're iterating over from within that same loop.  Alternatively you could create a temporary vector and append that to your initial `vectorA` when your done.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [std::vector::push_back() documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back):

> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

So for the first you cannot use reference to existing object as they are invalidated if relocation happens, for the last (even if new size is less or equal than capacity and no relocation happens) you cannot call `push_back()` for a vector you are using in range-based for loop, as that is using past-the-end iterator implicitly. Details can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

So possible solution could be to use temporary vector:

```
decltype(vectorA) tempVector;
for (auto &objectA: vectorA) {
   tempVector.push_back(objectA);
}
using moveIt = std::move_iterator<decltype(vectorA)::iterator>;
vectorA.insert( vectorA.end(), moveIt( tempVector.begin() ), moveIt( tempVector.end() ) );
```

Note: only letters, digits (not as the first symbol) and underscore can be used for variable identifiers so `objectA'` is not a valid identifier.

Comment: That's right, i made a mistake in my simplified code. But i did not make it in my real code. The real problem i'm experiencing is explained in my text.

Comment: @H.Sch I've already told you what problems you have - a) objects can be relocated and refence would be invalidated by `push_back()` and b) you cannot use `push_back()` inside ranged for loop for the vector you are iterating.

Comment: You could also `tempVector.reserve(vectorA.size());` before entering the loop in your solution to prevent reallocations.

Comment: @JustinRandall that would not help